# Testing Kotlin extensions inside a class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I know it's possible to [test global extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379450/how-should-i-test-kotlin-extension-functions), but how to test Kotlin extensions inside a class?

```
class D

class C {
  fun D.foo() {
    println("123")
  }
}
```

Should I interpret `D.foo` as private of `D` or can it be unit tested?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing extension functions inside classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702478/testing-extension-functions-inside-classes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either `with`, `apply` or `run` (or any other method that supplies the enclosing `C` instance) to access the `foo` method of `D`.

The reason why you can't access it directly is that `D.foo` is only accessible from an instance of type `C`.

Sample:

```
val c = C()
c.run { // apply or with
  D().foo() // accessible
}

D().foo() // not accessible
```

The following works too, but usage is not so nice:

```
D().run {
  C().run {
    foo() // accessible
  }
}
```

Funny thing: [this discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/extension-functions-inside-class/515/4) mentions that support for multiple receivers is in the backlog, but any further discussions just say that multiple receivers are not supported and there are no plans to support it. Maybe there is support in future and then the method to call it may become easier.

Comment: downvoting answers or questions without any comment why, is not really helpful. If the answer is wrong, then it may make sense and should be mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The `foo` function is a public method on `C`, but since a method call can't have two receivers, you have to use the `with` function. Like this:

```
with(C()) {
    D().foo()
}
```

Comment: or use `apply` or `run`